# Tensorflow Error: Constructing tensor of shape (120800) should match the length of values (121881)

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, p5.js

I am new to machine and new to tensorflow. As a method of learning, I have been following along with Dan Shiffman of the Coding Train as he shows how to create a color classifier.

I, however, wanted to do something different, so I collected data of hand-drawn shapes. Each shape has a label (square, circle, or triangle) and also has an array of 400 pixels (each picture was draw in a 20x20 grid). The data is stored in an object, which is contained within a JSON file.

Using p5.js's 'loadJSON' function, I can access the JSON file, iterate the entries, and create two arrays: 'shapes,' which is a an array of an array of pixels, and 'labels,' which is an array of the corresponding labels.

Below is the code, which utilizes p5's 'preload' and 'setup' functions.

```js
let data;

let model;

// list of labels from which you can get the oneHot index
let labelList = [
  "square",
  "circle",
  "triangle"
];

// function that is ran before setup
function preload() {
  data = loadJSON('shapeData.json'); // loads the json file
}

// called after preload
function setup() {

  let shapes = []; // an array of the pixels of hand-drawn shapes
  let labels = []; // the corresponding label of each hand-drawn shape
  
  // iterates over all of the entries in data
  for (let record of data.entries) {
    let pixels = record.pixels;
    shapes.push(pixels);
    labels.push(labelList.indexOf(record.label));
  }

  // ---------------- ERROR ------------------------ 
  let xs = tf.tensor2d(shapes);
  
  
  
  // these tensors work great
  let labelsTensor = tf.tensor1d(labels, 'int32');

  let ys = tf.oneHot(labelsTensor, 3);

}
```

The problem arises when I try to create the 'xs' as a tensor2d.

I get the error:

```
Error: Constructing tensor of shape (120800) should match the length of values (121881)
    at assert (tfjs@0.11.7:2)
    at new e (tfjs@0.11.7:2)
    at Function.e.make (tfjs@0.11.7:2)
    at Function.e.tensor (tfjs@0.11.7:2)
    at Object.e.tensor2d (tfjs@0.11.7:2)
    at setup (sketch.js:27)
    at p5.<anonymous> (p5.js:46551)
    at _runIfPreloadsAreDone (p5.js:46499)
    at p5._decrementPreload (p5.js:46509)
    at p5.js:59586
```

I have a total of 302 data points, each of which is an array of 400 binary numbers. Therefore the shape of the tensor should be [302, 400], and when I change the shape to something that is wrong (like [303, 401]) it gives an error saying that it should be [302, 400].

I am new to this whole process, so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the fix! The separate script which downloads the data had an error. This created data of different lengths...

For instance, one shape had 400 pixels and another had 410 pixels. This difference created a problem within tensorflow. After removing the data points that did not have 400 pixels, the program worked just fine!